# Duplicate symbol error while building OpenEars for emulator

Tags: iphone, ios, speech-to-text, openears

I am working in an iPhone application, I have used to OpenEars Framework to develop speech to text conversion in iPhone. Finally I run the application, I got error like this:

```
  Duplicate symbol _cmu_syl_boundary in /Users/govindarajk/Desktop/VoiceCue/
      VoiceCue/Framework/OpenEars.framework/OpenEars(OpenEars) and 
      /Users/govindarajk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
      VoiceCue-kiterlaofyegpferrereruumjpbrhzeich/Build/Intermediates
      /VoiceCue.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceCue.build/Objects-normal/
      i386/cmu_lex.o for architecture i386
```

Comment: I think there is multiple header search paths for same file. and check this site for openEars help http://www.politepix.com/

Answer (score 1):

check you might have duplicating the framework, this error occurs when a frameworks is added twice or some other framework of higher or lower version already added to project, hope that will help you